# std::ifstream initial value checks as true when uninitialized

Tags: c++, stream

I realized that when I test the value of a std::ifstream without initializing it, it checks as true.

How can I initialize my stream in a way that until I open the file I want to use, the check would return false ?

(Or maybe I should not use the value of the stream to determine if it is opened ?)

Small example to show the problem :

```
std::ifstream stream;

bool iWantToUseTheStream = false;

if (iWantToUseTheStream)
  stream.open(someFileName, std::fstream::in);

if (stream) // checks as true whether I opened the stream or not !
  std::cout << "I don't want this to print if I did not open the stream !";
```

Comment: Why not just check if the file [`is_open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/is_open) instead?

Comment: If the file name is wrong, perhaps, or you don't have permission to read the file, just know its name.

Comment: @NathanOliver That looks like that's what I should do ! Can't believe I had to ask on SO for such a simple thing haha. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @Norgannon Want me to write that up as an answer for you or do you just want to delete this?

Comment: @NathanOliver As you want

Comment: The stream is "false-y" when something has gone wrong or you've tried to read past the end. Neither of those has happened yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the state of the stream as a whole, you can use the [`is_open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/is_open) member function to check if the file is open.  That would make your code look like

```
std::ifstream stream;

bool iWantToUseTheStream = false;

if (iWantToUseTheStream)
  stream.open(someFileName, std::fstream::in);

if (stream.is_open()) // is only true if there is an open file
  std::cout << "I will only print if the file is open";
```